# Notice: Undefined index: fix with isset

Tags: php

I have a variable storing data like this.

```
$eddreldlc_auto_play = array(
    'loop_true' => array(
        'value' => 'true',
        'label' => 'True'
    ),
    'loop_false' => array(
        'value' => 'false',
        'label' => 'False'
    )
);
```

Now I am getting array data by using foreach like below

```
<?php
  $settings = get_option( 'eddreldlc_options', $eddreldlc_options );
  foreach( $eddreldlc_auto_play as $layout ) :
?>
<input type="radio" id="<?php echo $layout['value']; ?>" name="eddreldlc_options[eddreldlc_auto_play]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $layout['value'] ); ?>" <?php checked( $settings['eddreldlc_auto_play'], $layout['value'] ); ?> />
<label for="<?php echo $layout['value']; ?>"><?php echo $layout['label']; ?></label><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But, I am getting error: **Notice: Undefined index: eddreldlc_auto_play**

I googled there is a way to fix by using php isset. Used this, but still getting error. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a generic PHP problem and not necessarily a WordPress problem. In your code above you have `$settings['eddreldlc_auto_play']` but I do not see where you have the variable `$settings` initiated which is probably why it cannot find the index of `eddreldlc_auto_play`.

Comment: I am doing this in plugin option panel so I asked here. Can you give me correct code? or can you give me second code edited as answer? Thanks.

Comment: here is the settings variable. 

$settings = get_option( 'eddreldlc_options', $eddreldlc_options );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with the way you are doing it.

The following line reads your settings in...

```
$settings = get_option( 'eddreldlc_options', $eddreldlc_options );
```

So settings looks like:

```
array(
    'loop_true' => array(
        'value' => 'true',
        'label' => 'True'
    ),
    'loop_false' => array(
        'value' => 'false',
        'label' => 'False'
    )
);
```

Your loop looks like the following

```
foreach( $eddreldlc_auto_play as $layout )
```

So what you are actually getting is the following for each `$layout` variable

```
$layout = array( 
    'value' => 'true',
    'label' => 'True'
);
```

Yet you are referencing the following for checked:

```
$settings['eddreldlc_auto_play']
```

This does not compute as there is no such index in your `$settings` variable.

Judging by your code, you probably mean the following there

```
checked( $layout['value'], 'true' );
```

Of course, you have some other problems in that code. I'd rewrite it as follows:

```
<?php
    $settings = get_option( 'eddreldlc_options', $eddreldlc_options );
    foreach( $eddreldlc_auto_play as $layout ) {
        $value = esc_attr( $layout['value'] );
        $checked = checked( $layout['value'], 'true', false );
        echo <<<HTML
<input type="radio" id="eddreldlc_layout_{$layout['value']}" name="eddreldlc_autoplay" value="{$value}" {$checked} />
<label for="eddreldlc_layout_{$layout['value']}">{$layout['label']}</label><br />
HTML;

    }
```

- Your id is very prone to being stomped on so I made it more unique
- Your name on the radio makes it look like you are setting the option in your site to stomp on the array you claim to be reading so I changed the name to avoid confusion on what is being expected.
- I personally prefer heredoc notation as it makes for much easier reading

Anywise, fix the referenced index and you should be good to go.